# Not able to add android platform using AVD manager - not able to fetch the url from AVD

Tags: android

I wanted to start working on android but having installation issues. When I start the AVD Manager and check the **repository.xml url** it **gives** me an **error** "... not able to fetch the url. Connection timeout." the same thing happens if I use http or https but if i try to open the url in my browser, it returns the response. I do not have a manual proxy set in the browser but do have an automatic proxy configuration url. I tried copying that url to the internet section in AVD but still no response returned. Also, we do not have the permission to turn off the firewall.
Is there a place where i can download the SDK **Platform** Android (1.6 preferred)?

Answer (score 1):

Consult [this](http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html)
HTH

Answer (score 1):

if you look in the folder where you have the sdk installed, you will see both the avd manager and the sdk manager. click on the sdk manager and you will be able to install additional platforms from there. Still not showing up in my AVD manager, but Android 4.0 is downloading so i no longer care :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the android developer "quick start" for about a week.  This problem has not been solved or at least not explained anywhere.  It's been happening for a couple of years now.  2008 is the first record of a problem.  All suggestions have failed.  "change 'https' to 'http'" etc.

cM

Answer (score 0):

I came across this with a similar answer.

I used the installer, and it didn't install the AVD manager. Going back to the developer files I grabbed the 'rar' and ran the 'adk manager' to get the files I needed. This installed the files to set the target when creating the AVD.

Worked for me.